# What does ntdll.dll!LdrAccessResource do? It's hogging my CPU in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cpu, windows-explorer, threads, svchost

I've had this problem for about a year (I don't want to reinstall Windows because it's too much work, and my C-drive backups are too new so they contain the problem too). I've upgraded Windows 10 several times, now running version 2004. The problem follows on each version.

The problem is either explorer.exe or svchost.exe randomly runs on very high CPU loads. Somewhere from 5–60 %. It varies randomly. When using Process Hacker to investigate, it's most of the time the thread ntdll.dll!LdrAccessResource that is using the most CPU.

What does this thread do? Are there any tools to try to fix these kinds of problems? I already tried chkdsk, sfc /scannow, Tweaking.com Windows Repair, clean boot (the last of which I couldn't properly do because I couldn't then enter Windows anymore).

Comment: __ntdll.dll!LdrAccessResource__ Sounds Like you have a problem with malware or maybe even a virus. If you can, run an antivirus before loading Windows. You should be able to run Windows Defender before your computer loads the entire operating system. Good luck Jim

Comment: Have you seen this page ? "How to Fix Ntdll.dll Crash Error on Windows 10" https://softwaretested.com/windows/how-to-fix-ntdll-dll-crash-error-on-windows-10/

Comment: This is a basic function that gets called all of the time.. The only way to know why it is hanging is to look at the call stack for the process that is calling it (which you won't know how to do or how to read).  "How to Fix Ntdll.dll Crash Error.." IMHO is a waste of time.. it can't hurt.. but has NEVER helped me yet.  My advice?  For starters, check the drive for errors, If the drive check has errors, THEN do the DISM and SFC junk.  Otherwise create a NEW user.. log in as that user and see if it still happens (profile corrupt?). Install free Malware Bytes and run a scan JIC (I doubt this)

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: I found the culprit to this problem. It was extremely difficult to pinpoint the source of the problem as there were absolutely no hints pointing to the culprit. It was svchost.exe or explorer.exe using high CPU. However, simply uninstalling a certain anti-virus software also removed the problem. So if you encounter a similar problem, try uninstalling all anti-virus programs.